# Place logo inside <div class="sections nav-sections"> in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I wanted to place logo infront of navigation bar in magento 2, that to inside the div

Answer (score 6):

1 ) **Adding Div to logo** in logo.phtml

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
```

**2 ) Move to navigation section** using default.xml

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

<move element="logo" destination="navigation.sections" before"-" />
```

**3)** Then adjust CSS as per your requirement

let me know if any problem

Thanks

Comment: logo gets disappeared..! I dont know why

Comment: if working online then please pass the URL to check ... or try inspecting in browser ..is there logo present in the code..

Comment: no logo found on inspection

Comment: try clearing your cache , or if pass url if possible

Comment: my logo dissapears as well

Comment: could you pass the URL please , this is tested on extended LUMA theme

Comment: @manoj deswal please check your answer        <move element="logo" destination="navigation.sections" before ="-" />

Comment: after move logo to menu bar, in my mobile view menu link not working, any help thanks @Manoj Deswal

Answer (score 4):

Move logo to navigation section use bellow code

**app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<move element="logo" destination="catalog.topnav" before="-"/>
```

Comment: Hello @Sarvesh Tiwari, after move logo to menu bar, in my mobile view menu link not working, any help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to your theme **default.xml**

You can use this approach to move a block:

```
   <move element="logo" destination="nav-sections" />
```

with attributes "**before**" or "**after**".

You can use "before" = "-" to place your element at the very begin of the destination and  "after" = "-" to place your element at the very end of the destination.

Comment: no logo found on inspection

Comment: after move logo to menu bar, in my mobile view menu link not working, any help thanks @Suresh Chikani